# How can I fix uninitialized value in numeric eq (==)

Tags: perl

How can I fix this error:

```
[Fri Dec 11 12:07:24.417565 2015] [cgi:error] [pid 10838] [client     24.32.36.240:54536] AH01215:  [Fri Dec 11 12:07:24 2015] 
uu_upload.pl: Use of uninitialized value in numeric eq (==) at uu_upload.pl     line 350.:  /home/public_html/cgi-bin/uu_upload.pl, 
referer: http://www.....com/uploader.php
```

Line 349 - Line 353 shows:

```
# Force 'redirect_using_location' if user does not have a javascript capable     browser or using embedded_upload_results
if($query->param('no_script') || $query->param('embedded_upload_results') ==     1){
 $main::config->{redirect_using_js_html} = 0;
 $main::config->{redirect_using_location} = 1;
}
```

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: `$query->param('embedded_upload_results')` is undefined. You might want to handle that possibility.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `defined` function you can check the variable is defined.

```
if ( defined($variable) && $variable == 10 ) {
    ...
}
```